# WF: Determining if workflow completed

Tags: workflow-foundation

How do I determine from the host if a workflow instance has compled or not besides subscribing to the WorkfloRuntime's WorkflowCompleted event? Is there any flag or state I can check for a given WorflowInstance to determine if it has completed?

**@Edit:** The question is about sequential workflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (at least for know, from what I've learned) is that there's no flag associated with a WorkflowInstance that you can retrieve for a given instance indicating whether the instance has completed.

The **two approaches available** are:

1. [WorkflowRuntime.WorkflowCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.runtime.workflowruntime.workflowcompleted.aspx)
2. Using a [TrackingService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.runtime.tracking.trackingservice.aspx) service to keep a 'log' of workflow execution and quering the log to destermine if a workflow instance has completed. Here is a [good introductory article](http://odetocode.com/articles/457.aspx). With this approach the only available out-of-the-box implementation of TrackingService is [SqlTrackingService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.runtime.tracking.sqltrackingservice.aspx), which requires a SQL Server database. You can then use [SqlTrackingQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.runtime.tracking.sqltrackingservice.aspx) to query the 'log'

**Note:** An interesting aspect of the behaviour of SqlTrackingService is that it won't *by default* immediatly write the messages it receives from the runtime to the database, but only at the end of transactions. This behaviour is controlled by [IsTransactional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.runtime.tracking.sqltrackingservice.istransactional.aspx) property of SqlTrackingService.

Answer (score 1):

You can to check `TrackingServices` to know what current state for a workflow instance.

There are some code snippets here: [.NET 3.0
State Machines In Windows Workflow](http://odetocode.com/Articles/460.aspx) .

Comment: Thanks for your help! From what I see the 'completness' check can be implemented using a TrackingService, but used for just this purpose it seems a bit cumbersome, even more than the event approach. And the two approaches look similar in the sense that you have to subscibe beforehand, you can't just grab an arbitrary workflow instance and get its state. However if it works and WWF is designed this way it should not be a problem. I'm just curious why there's so little info in the WorkfloInstance itself, there should be a reason

Comment: Another option is to use `System.Workflow.Activities.StateMachineWorkflowInstance` combined to `WorkflowInstance.GetWorkflowDefinition()` to tell if `smwi.CurrentState` is final state.